# flutter animated splash screen (gif)

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

in drawable folder
i added gif image file(splashscreen.gif)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/splashscreen" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```

and i add like this.
but only first image of gif is shown. how can i use animated splash screen or gif image?
i saw how to make splash screen but almost they make other class(like MyApp) and use `navigator` but for me i need http call and location reqeust before run app. so i need slpash screen before run app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot add animated splash screens, splash screens need to be static images. You can add the first image of your .gif as a splash screen, then navigate to another page that has the same starting view as your splash screen image, request what you need to your network services, await for the response, and then animate from there.

That is, essentially, what the iOS Twitter app does when you launch it. Here is its animated "splash screen".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used only a color as native splash screen for iOS and Android and did the animated splash screen with Flutter. In fact i did the Splash Animation with Flare (and put the flare runtime into flutter) and simply used that code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(250, 224, 61, 1.0),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
              child: FlareActor(
                "assets/flare/splash.flr",
                callback: (nameOfAnimation) =>
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/login"),
                fit: BoxFit.none,
                animation: "splash",
              )),
        ));
  }
}
```

Important thing here is to have the same native splash colors as in this code which is: **const Color.fromRGBO(250, 224, 61, 1.0),**

When the animation is finished the callback is called which routes to the Login Screen.

Comment: how can i edit '*.flr' file online or offline?