# Add loading spinner to splash screen

Tags: flutter, spinner, loading, splash-screen

I just added a splash screen to my app using [`flutter_native_splash`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package, and it works really fine.

How can I add a loading spinner to my splash screen?

Answer (score 1):

From their [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#are-animationslottiegif-images-supported),

> Are animations/lottie/GIF images supported? #
> Not at this time. However, you may want to consider a secondary splash screen that supports animation. See the secondary splash screen recommendation.

You can only display an image as a splash screen as of now.

Comment: do you know if there is another package i could make a splash screen with loading spinner?

Comment: The default splash screen can not be animated (android 12 might change that). Here is an alternative solution to your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592492/flutter-animated-splash-screen-gif